# SSIS with MySQL and without SQL Server

Tags: mysql, ssis

Our Organization is planning to cut costs on SQL Sever licenses. We use  SSIS for our ETLs. Is it possible to install only SSIS with a MySQL server and  without SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't run SSIS without also running the SQL Server engine, which means paying a license.

The reason for this is quite simple, SSIS is a SQL Server component/feature. It is integrated in the SQL Server Engine.
And you will at a minimum require a [standard SQL Server edition to use the SSIS runtime](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/integration-services-features-supported-by-the-editions-of-sql-server).

Answer (score 0):

I think no. There is used MS SQL Server to store SSISDB, so you can't install SSIS without SQL Server. You can split SSIS out from SQL server and use one server for SSIS and the other server for databases. If you do this, you will need to license both servers which will drive up costs.